# Setting Pitch in PlaybackParams crashes app

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using AudioManager to record the audio.

So, Whenever I try to set pitch using setPitch function my app crashes.

**Note:** samplerate = 8500

**Here is the code**

```
            buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                    SecurityException, IllegalStateException {

                buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(true);

                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AudioSavePathInDevice);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                params.setPitch(samplerate);
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(params);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording Playing",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

**And here is the Error**

```
    2020-02-20 18:43:33.574 9544-9577/com.mycompany.testaudio E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2020-02-20 18:43:33.587 9544-9592/com.mycompany.testaudio E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@f96188d
2020-02-20 18:43:37.561 9544-9544/com.mycompany.testaudio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mycompany.testaudio, PID: 9544
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(Native Method)
        at com.mycompany.testaudio.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:162)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6659)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Answer (score 0):

`8500` is way too high of a "pitch shift" factor. A safe range for this parameter might be somewhere between `0.5` - `3.0` (a guess). `1.0` corresponds to "no pitch shift".

Unfortunately I could not find documentation on what the actual limits are; you may have to resort to simply `catch`-ing the exception, to determine if a value you've supplied is out-of-range.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept this answer :)